# Adding widget to lockscreen i developed in android

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen

I have developed a lockscreen in android and i wanted to know if it is possible to add default widgets of android to this lockscreen , if Yes HOW?

Comment: cn u plz post wht u hve tried ? u want create lock screen widget ? or normal home screen widget ? or u hve create ur own lock screen there u want ?

Comment: I have a normal lockscreen which unlocks by swiping but i want to add the inbuilt music widget to it.

Comment: lke this  http://goo.gl/VBua4p ?... To display media player control on lock screen you can use RemoteControlClient. check this link http://goo.gl/tksF8  its availble above api level 14 .

Comment: yes something like this...Thank you